# How to use str_extract_all in R in data frame without returning a list?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been trying to extract multiple patterns in a sequence in a data frame of each row and returning those patterns in a new column. But the problem is i get a list if i use str_extract_all and i don't how to unlist.

I have been trying to use the code at the bottom. The unnest does not work either neither does unlist in mutate function.

[image]

```
dc <- z %>%
   mutate(sequence_match = str_extract_all(z$Sequence,
                                           c("R..S", "R..T", "R..Y")))
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please do not post data as an image because then we cannot copy/paste the data for testing. What version of `dplyr` are you using?

Comment: I flagged it for more clarity, a reprex is most needed

Answer (score 1):

You can return one comma-separated string of values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dc = z %>% 
  mutate(sequence_match = sapply(str_extract_all(Sequence, 
                                 c("R..S", "R..T", "R..Y"), toString)))
```

Comment: Doesn't `"R..S|R..T|R..Y"` work better than `c("R..S", "R..T", "R..Y")`?

Comment: Maybe/maybe not. I copied it from OP's attempt since they said it is working for them but just giving the output as list.

Comment: Okay, also not sure about the number/placement of parentheses in your solution ;)

Comment: This works: `df %>% 
  mutate(sequence_match = sapply(str_extract_all(x,"R..S|R..T|R..Y"), toString))` with this data: `df <- data.frame(
  x = c("RTTTFGDSZZZGGRETS", "JJHBRTTPPHBRHSSS", "LKNOJPRRRYVCERSW", 
       "FGAWQLMNBRFRWXT"))`